# Using an SSD in an Acer Timeline laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have an Acer Timeline 13" laptop and was wondering if I can use an internal solid state disk with it, and if so what type of SSD do I need?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any restriction on which SSD you could choose, because most SSDs use the 2.5" form factor which would be needed for a laptop. The main considerations are the data capacity needed (which affects the cost) and the performance of the drive.

There are other practical issues to consider such as figuring out how to physically remove and replace the hard-drive, reinstalling the OS on the new drive, and obtaining drivers for all hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can locate all the drivers no problem, I only use as a dev machine so I dont have need for 160GB of storageb so I think about 60GB wil do the job.  

Whats the difference in performance your talking about?

Comment: @John Most SSDs are far superior to HDDs in terms of random read/write performance, but there are differences between the various SSD brands. I'd recommend [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/tag/storage) and [PC Perspective](http://www.pcper.com/article.php?aid=736&type=expert&pid=1) for providing good coverage of SSDs. The latest SSD comparison from AnandTech is [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3756/2010-value-ssd-100-roundup-kingston-and-ocz-take-on-intel/2). The *random* read/write speeds are usually more important than the *sequential* read/write speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Any 2.5" SSD.

You may want to read some reviews from Anandtech.com

Intel SSDs are recommended.